# How can i add a sound and listen it just 1 time, not repeatedly. (Python)

Tags: python, audio

I was using `import winsound` and I'd like to listen to this `winsound.PlaySound("ending.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)` just 1 time but it's repeating itself

```
if health == 0:
    maxYhedefler = 0

    maxZhedefler = 0

    speed = 0

    sınır1.penup()
    sınır1.hideturtle()
    sınır1.setposition(-360, 0)
    bittistring = "You died,Score:",skor2
    sınır1.write(bittistring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
    winsound.PlaySound("bitis.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

That was the line I was using, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Change `winsound.PlaySound("ending.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)` to `winsound.PlaySound("ending.mp3", winsound.SND_FILENAME)`. Or, try using `playsound` instead:

```
from playsound import playsound


if health == 0:
    maxYhedefler = 0

    maxZhedefler = 0

    speed = 0

    sınır1.penup()
    sınır1.hideturtle()
    sınır1.setposition(-360, 0)
    bittistring = "You died,Score:",skor2
    sınır1.write(bittistring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
    playsound("bitis.mp3")
```

---

If the `if` statement is inside a `while` loop, add `played = False` above the `while` loop, then:

```
if health == 0:
    maxYhedefler = 0

    maxZhedefler = 0

    speed = 0

    sınır1.penup()
    sınır1.hideturtle()
    sınır1.setposition(-360, 0)
    bittistring = "You died,Score:",skor2
    sınır1.write(bittistring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
    if not played:
        playsound("bitis.mp3")
        played = True
```

Comment: SND_FILENAME did the same thing as SND_ALIAS. I copy-pasted the code you gave me, didn't work, it says "No module named 'playsound' ". I guess i couldn't make it(?)

Comment: @Cempal You need to go to your cmd, and enter `pip install playsound` for the module.

Comment: @Cempal Did you install playsound?

Comment: yes i installed playsound, tried it again and said the same thing. Then i upgraded the playsound and also didn't work.
if statment is inside a while loop like you said. I add "played = False" above the while loop and
 " if not played:
    playsound("bitis.mp3")
    played = True"
also didn't work

Comment: @Cempal Could it be that the sound file has repeating sound in it?

Comment: No, i am sure. I think i will use turtle.bye() because sound doesn't repeat and game is closing when the sound ends

Comment: @Cempal Can you post your `while` loop with the `played=False`?

Comment: played = False

while True:
  ...
     ....

      if  health == 0:
        maxYhedefler = 0

        maxZhedefler = 0

        speed = 0

        sınır1.penup()
        sınır1.hideturtle()
        sınır1.setposition(-360, 0)
        bittistring = "Canınız kalmadı,Skorunuz:", skor2
        sınır1.write(bittistring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
        if not played:
            playsound("bitis.mp3")
            played = True

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't give space between lines

Comment: @Cempal No worries, just post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Ann Zen

#While#

carpmarotasi = (150,180)

skor = 100

health = 3

skor2 = 0

played = False

while True:

```
 ....
   ....


if health == 0:

  maxYhedefler = 0

  maxZhedefler = 0

  speed = 0

  sınır1.penup()
  sınır1.hideturtle()
  sınır1.setposition(-360, 0)
  bittistring = "Canınız kalmadı,Skorunuz:", skor2
  sınır1.write(bittistring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
  if not played:
      playsound("bitis.mp3")
      played = True
```